# Upload file using AJAX in CodeIgniter Still executed even the value is null/undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I want to execute another ajax if the file is not input yet. But it still posting the form action.

Here is my view code :

```
<form method="POST" id="quiz_file" action="<?php echo site_url('home/upload_quiz/' . $kelas);?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input name="filequiz" id="filequiz" type="file" />
</form>
```

And this is my JS :

```
$('#submitquiz').on('click', function(event) {
  var inputFile = $('input[name=filequiz]');
  document.getElementById('submitquiz').disabled = true;
  var fileToUpload = inputFile[0].files[0];
  // make sure there is file to upload
  if (undefined != fileToUpload) 
  {
     var uploadURI = $('#quiz_file').attr('action');
     var formData = new FormData();
     formData.append("file", fileToUpload);
     alert('if');
     $.ajax({
        url: uploadURI,
        type: 'post',
        data: 
        {
            formData : formData,
            asid : asid_quiz,
            value : cmbValue
        },
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(data) 
        {

        }
    });
 }
 else
 {
   alert('else');
   $.ajax(
   {        
     type: 'POST',
     url:'<?php echo site_url("home/assignment_score"); ?>',
     data: 
     { 
        asid : asid_quiz,
        value : cmbvalue,
        kelas : <?php echo $kelas;?>,
        dataType:"JSON"
     },
     success: function(data) 
     {
        console.log('asdasd' + data);
        alert('Quiz score submitted');
     }
 });
```

When i just executed it, it show alert message "else". But it still perform the upload action from form action.

How this could be happen ? How to stop performing the upload action and perform the another ajax request in  that 'else' side ?

Comment: Can you use jquery.form plugin , http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload

Comment: if `#submitquiz` is a input with `type="submit"` then you need to prevent the "default" action of the submit button ... i.e. `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: are you getting my point ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your submitquiz button type is submit you have to prevent submit event on click or you can change it to input type button.

I prefer you too if you are send data using ajax then you have to use input button instead of submit

```
$('#submitquiz').on('click', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
```

Comment: can i continue again after using that method ?

Comment: yes you can add your below this method or just change the button type

Comment: I mean after im using event.preventDefault, i want to continue to perform action again. How to do it ?

Comment: for that you can use  $( "#quiz_file" ).submit(); for submit form. make sure id is form id because we submit form