# Send multiple content-type Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have succeed upload image using ajax with codeigniter. But now i want to sending array too so i can insert data inside controller and model.

This is my code for better explanation :

```
<form method="POST" id="quiz_file" action="<?php echo site_url('home/upload_quiz/' . $kelas);?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="filequiz" id="filequiz" type="file" />
</form>

This is the controller :
function upload_quiz($kelas) 
{
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["filequiz"]["name"]);
    $extension = end($temp);
    $new_name = time() . "." . $extension; 
    $config['upload_path']          = './assets/images/quiz_images/';
    $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
    $config['max_size']             = 2000;
    $config['file_name']            = $new_name;
    $config['max_width']            = 10000;
    $config['max_height']           = 10000;
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
    $data['user_name'] = $session_data['user_name'];
    $data['kelas'] = $kelas;
    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('filequiz'))
    {
        print_r(array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors()));
        $data['error'] = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $this->load->view('course', $data);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->model('Model');
        $asid = $this->input->post('asid');
        $value = $this->input->post('value');
        $this->Model->inputassignmentscore($asid,$value); <---- The error come from this
        $data['status'] = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        $quiz_name = $this->input->post('quiz_name');
        if($this->Model->input_quiz($quiz_name,$new_name,$kelas) == TRUE)
        {   
            echo $asid;
            $this->load->view('course', $data);
        }
        elseif($this->Model->input_quiz($quiz_name,$new_name,$kelas) == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('course', $data);
        }
    } 
}
```

This is the script code

```
var cmbvalue = [];
if(asid_quiz.length > 0)
{
    for(i=0;i<asid_quiz.length;i++)
    {
        cmbass = document.getElementsByName('quizcmb')[i].value;
        cmbvalue.push(cmbass);
        console.log('cmbass : ' + cmbvalue);
    }
}

$.ajax({
url: uploadURI,
type: 'post',
data: 
{
    formData : formData,
    asid : asid_quiz,
    value : cmbvalue
},
processData: false,
contentType: false,
beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
},
success: function(data) 
{
}
});
```

The formData is sending correctly. But the `asid` and `value` is empty. So i cannot insert data using controller and model.
How can i fix this ?

This is the complete code if you want to see : [this is my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44403475/upload-file-using-ajax-in-codeigniter-still-executed-even-the-value-is-null-unde)

When i try using console or alert, the value is exists.

Comment: have you ever defined asid_quiz or cmbvalue? Where do these variables come from?

Comment: Yes i do.. that variables come from ID value from html page. See my edited post

Comment: can you show us php code also check data in console log and in inspect element

Comment: See my updated post

Answer (score 0):

while sending Ajax data, you send (name: string,value:string) pair.Since cmbvalue is an array, you need to convert it into string. May be array to CSV or some string that can be parsed.
if cmbvalue=[apple,banana] you might want to send it as string cmbval="apple,banana" while sending it in data and parse csv/string in server side.
In Javascript, to convert array to string using toString()

```
data: 
{
    formData : formData,
    asid : asid_quiz,
    value:cmbval.toString();
}
```

Comment: does it will be considered as array in the controller ?

Comment: It will be considered as a string in controller parameter. But you can convert into array using php explode() function. $arr=explode(",",$cmbval);

Comment: what does console.log(cmbval) shows?If its not empty, Then it  should be working. In my above code sample, the code should be value:cmbval.toString(); as per your variables used in controller. My mistake.

Comment: It returns white space.. What is the differences between the old and the new one in your code ?

Comment: Before it was cmbvalue:cmbval.tostring() and I changed it to value:cmbval.tostring()

Comment: if you console.log in here is white space. Then there is sth wrong here. cmbass is not assigned value. which means document.getElementsByName('quizcmb')[i].value;  part is not working

Comment: can you do console.log for cmbvalue.toString(). If it has value, then it should be posted. Otherwise I am not sure whats going on.

Comment: This is the console.log(cmbval.toString()); => cmbass : 60,78

Comment: May be you need to check in controller what you have received in 
$this->input->post('value'). Still nothing in there?

Answer (score 0):

```
var asid_quiz = ['1','2','3'];
var cmbvalue = [];
for(i=0;i<asid_quiz.length;i++)
    {
        cmbass = asid_quiz[i];
        cmbvalue.push(cmbass);
        console.log('cmbass : ' + cmbvalue);
    }
$.ajax({  
    type: 'POST',  
    url: 'test.php', 
    data: { album: 'test',asid:'asid_quiz',value:cmbvalue },

    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: it shows => TypeError: 'append' called on an object that does not implement interface FormData.